# Add item to UITableView dynamically without having direct connection with datasource

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, swift2

How to add an item to UITableView on runtime ?

Tried adding cell.contentView.addSubView, but its adding the item as overlay.

Also, I don't have direct connection with the tableview or the datasource, but got it from a rootview by traversal process.
Due to this, the index of the cell is getting wrong.
The cell orders are different when i checked the cell array by debugging.

So is it a right way to inject the subview to one cell without having direct hook with the datasource ?

Comment: Sounds like you need to refactor.  Traversing view controller hierarchies is generally a hack. You need to ask the tableview for the cell for the required row

Comment: i made that. But adding the item (UIButton) is visible only when the frame coordinates are added. But this will place the location as mentioned in the frame not inside the cell. And its acting as a overlay view as well.

Comment: As I said, refactor and rethink your approach. The view should probably be part of your cell and hidden/shown based on a property of your data model. Having a random class reach in to the cell views and add views is just a bad idea. That class shoukd somehow uodatebthe data model Andre inform the tableview controller. You could use a delegation pattern or `NotificationCenter`

Comment: I think i should not follow what I was trying to: add button view by traversing the view object, finding the table cell, and moreover, i don't having direct access to the datasource. The datasource object which i got from the view object hierarchy is not providing 'append' property also. So I think i should add the button from my custom framework itself.